# Laravel 5.2 - How to get id of newly created user and pass it to a controller

Tags: laravel

I've never used Laravel before and I'm working on a 3 part registration using laravels default user registration & auth for step 1 of the form. Each step has its own table. The id column of step 1s table is used to link all 3 tables.

Currently im using `$id = Auth::user()->id` to get the logged in users id in the step 2 controller. Instead how can I route/pass the id after the user is created to step 2 controllers store method and redirect the view to step 2?

in authcontroller

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    return User::create([
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'firstName' => $data['firstName'],
        'middleName' => $data['middleName'],
        'lastName' => $data['lastName'],
    ]);
}
```

in Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));

    // pass id to store method in profile and redirect to profileinfo 
    return view('user/profileinfo');
}

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with using $id = Auth::user()->id ?

Comment: @Abhishek Because in each controller than I will have to have a getId function that makes sure each user is logged in and returns the id. I was thinking that its better to pass id as a parameter to the store method in each controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `create()` method which returns `true` or `false`, you should use `save()` method which returns the model:

```
$id = $data->save()->id;
```

But if you still need short syntax, you can use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment):

```
$userModel = new User($data);
$userModel->save();
$id = $userModel->id;
```

Comment: I am a little confused. You said not to use save in the other comment. Do I add `$id = $data->save()->id;` in the current create method? Or do I replace create?

Comment: I don't think I said you shouldn't use `save()` method. I'll try to explain. You can use `create()` method, because it's a great shortcut. But, if you need to get last inserted id, you have no choice here and should use plain old `save()` method.

Answer (score 8):

You can change create method in AuthController in this way :

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user =  User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

    ]);

    $id= $user->id; // Get current user id

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: This answer is best, the tick marked answer creates login implementation failed;

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach:

```
$data = new FooModel(); // or in your case User();
$data->column_1 = 'value_1';
$data->column_2 = 'value_2';
$data->save();
```

and now after calling `save()`, `$data->id` should give you last inserted ID, so that you can use it wherever you want.

Just keep in mind, that if the PK column (the one with ID) is **not auto-increment**, it will always return 0.

Comment: If I change the create method to use save instead of User::create will that change/mess up authentication? I rather stick with the default authentication if thats the case

Comment: Messing around with DB operations (inserting in this case) has nothing to do with authentication. Try the approach before complaining. :)

Comment: Honestly wasn't complaining I was genuinely wondering. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. Always start wondering after you did some work, not before. That will save you a lot of time. :) Good luck! Please accept the answer if that did the trick.

Comment: @michealb, if you change `save()` to `create()` it will not work, as `create()` returns `true` or `false`, but not the model.

Comment: @alexeymezenin I suspected this. Do you have any suggestions/ideas on how else to do it?

Comment: @michealb, you still need to use `save()` method, but if you want a short syntax, check my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `create()` function to

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
  $user = new User();
  $user->email = $data['email'];
  $user->password = bcrypt($data['password']),
  $user->firstName = $data['firstName'],
  $user->middleName = $data['middleName'],
  $user->lastName = $data['lastName'];
  $user->save();

  return $user->id;
 }
```